# how to pass the value of input to my bar chart

Tags: php, chart.js

I have 3 input fields and a submit button i just want to display the bar chart according to the input value when i press the submit button

I test the value on alert and i can that I'm getting it

here's the html

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Enter Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value1" name="value1" placeholder="Enter value">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value2" name="value2" placeholder="Enter value">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter Value</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value3" name="value3" placeholder="Enter value">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getVal()">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

heres the javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      function getVal()
      {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
        var val2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
        var val3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
      }
      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
          // The type of chart we want to create
          type: 'bar',

          // The data for our dataset
          data: {
              labels: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
              datasets: [{
                  label: 'My First dataset',
                  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                  data: [0, 10, 2, 20, 30, 45] <------ How can i pass val1,val2,val3 here data:[] is an object type

              }]
          },
      });
```

there's no error but there's no result as well i just want to pass the val1,val2,va3 on data:[0,10,2,20]

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the val1, val2 and val3 variables as global variables outside the function. Currently val1 val2 and val3 are only available in the getVal() function.

A better way to do it would be to create an array, and add the values to it, like so:

```
var values = [];
values.push(document.getElementById('value1').value);
values.push(document.getElementById('value2').value);
values.push(document.getElementById('value3').value);
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'bar',
    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: values
        }]
    },
});
```